# Ruby cucumber scenario hook execution order

Tags: ruby, cucumber, hook, scenarios

I have an After hook that gets executed before a hook on the scenario itself.  I want to reverse the order of those hooks running.  Currently the "After do" hook is running before the "After('@66075')" and the cleanup in the 66075 has to run first.

My hooks

```
After('@66075') do
  begin
    #cleanup
  rescue => detail
    puts detail.message
    puts detail.backtrace.join("\n")
  end
end

After do |scenario|
  begin
    if scenario.failed?
      #do stuff
    end
  rescue
    puts "process for failing scenarios failed"
  end
  begin
    @browser.link(:text, 'Logout').click
    sleep(0.5)
    @browser.alert.ok if @browser.alert.exists?
  rescue => detail
    puts detail.message
    puts detail.backtrace.join("\n")
    puts "logout and close windows failed"
  end
end
```

and my scenario:

```
 @66075 
  Scenario: my Scenario
    Given A
    When B
    Then C
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[After hooks run in the opposite order to that in which they appear in your support/*.rb files.](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks#scenario-hooks) Whether a hook is specific to a tag or not doesn't affect the order it runs in. To make your tagged hook run before your untagged hook, put your tagged hook after your untagged hook.

Comment: The above doc is moved to following link
https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#hooks

Answer (score 0):

Before hooks run in the same order in which they are declared.
https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#hooks